# Valgrind error with atoi

Tags: c, valgrind

I am working on this project and when I run valgrind on this line of code

```
  int numPointers;
  numPointers = atoi(argv[NUM_POINTERS_VALUE]);
```

I get a valgrind error of

> Invalid read of size 1 [PID: 8979]
>   Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) freed

I was wondering what is going on here and if there is a way to fix it

Comment: `NUM_POINTERS_VALUE` should always be `< argc`

Comment: What does the macro `NUM_POINTERS_VALUE` contain and what command do you execute to run `valgrind` ?

Comment: @Axalo it is. In this case, my argc is 2 while NUM_POINTERS_VALUE = 1

Comment: @SantoshA I am right clicking on my project and profiling as valgrind (the way my professors taught us)

Comment: What is the value you are passing through command line arguement?

Comment: @Gopi it is just an int, in this case a 10

Comment: @John. You get that error `==9867== Invalid read of size 1
==9867==    at 0xC3281C: ____strtol_l_internal (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==9867==    by 0xC3257F: strtol (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==9867==    by 0xC2EF60: atoi (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==9867==    by 0x804840C: main (tm.c:7)
==9939==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
`                        only when  your executable did not receive the command line argument. Try to print the `argv[1]` before using it

Answer (score 2):

When you are using command line arguments it is always a good practice to use

```
   int main()
   { 
     if(argc != <required number of argument>)
     {
       printf("Fewer arguments in the input\n");
       return 1;
     }
     // Do your stuff
   }
```

Later

```
if(argc[1] != NULL)
numPointers = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Because `atoi(NULL)` results in undefined behavior leading to crash.

Comment: Note that it would be better if the error message was reported on standard error rather than standard output, if the error message gave the expected usage, and if the error return status was not 0 (meaning OK or 'success').  Use either 1 or `EXIT_FAILURE` as the return value.